# Running a production SPSS job on remote server from command line

Tags: spss

We have a Windows based SPSS server say 10.20.30.40. We would like to kick off a SPSS Production job from another server 10.20.30.50.

Can we kick off the job using a batch file?

Answer (score 1):

1.Create an SPJ file in production.
2.make a bat file to run spj

"C:\Program Files\IBM\SPSS\Statistics\21\stats.exe" -production "K:\Meinzer\Production\SPJ\DashBoardInsert.spj"

1. create a 'scheduled task' in windows.

The real issue is getting your output from the job.  for that, i use python.

I use syntax like this

```
begin program.
AlertDays=4
Files=['k:\meinzer/Production\dashboarddatasets/aod_network_report.sps',
'k:\meinzer/Production\push/aod_network_reportpush.sps',
'k:\meinzer/Production\pushproduction/aod_network_reportpushP.sps']
end program.
insert file='k:/meinzer/production/ps/errorTestPickles.sps'.
```

to trigger this

```
*still needs error info passed.

set mprint=off /printback=on.

begin program.

#test files to observe - uncomment out 8 or 9
#Files=['k:\meinzer/Production\dashboarddatasets/test.sps']
#Files=['k:\meinzer/Production\dashboarddatasets/testfail.sps']
#Files=['k:\meinzer/Production\dashboarddatasets/clinfo.sps']
#Files=['k:\meinzer/Production\dashboarddatasets/CSOC_Consecutive_High_Level_Svcs.sps']

import shutil
import spss
import re, os, pickle
from datetime import datetime

def main(Files):
    """The parser and processor for Syntax Error Reporting """
    try:
        for FilePath in Files:
                Start = datetime.now().replace( microsecond=0)
                DBname, init_Syntax = init_Vars(FilePath)
                cmds = init_cmds(init_Syntax)
                cmd=''
                cmd2=''
                cmd3=''
                try:
                    for cmd in cmds:
                     cmd=cmd.replace('\r\n','\n ')
                     cmd=cmd.replace('\t',' ')
                     print cmd
                     spss.Submit(cmd)  
                     cmd3=cmd2
                     cmd2=cmd    
#                    cmd, cmd2, cmd3=run_cmds(cmd,cmd2,cmd3,cmds) 
                    Finish = datetime.now().replace( microsecond=0)                    
                    spss_Output(DBname)       
                    SavedNewname=check_saved_new_name(DBname)
                    if SavedNewname==1:
                        send_result(DBname,'Failure',Start,Finish,0,cmd,cmd2,cmd3)
                        break
                    if SavedNewname==0:
                        send_result(DBname,'Success',Start,Finish,1,AlertDays)
                except Exception,e:   
                    Finish = datetime.now().replace( microsecond=0)
                    errorLevel, errorMsg = get_spss_error(e)
                    send_result(DBname,"Failure in code",Start,Finish,0,AlertDays,cmd,cmd2,cmd3,errorLevel, errorMsg )
                    spss_Output(DBname)
                    break

    except IOError:
        print "can't open file or difficulty initializing comands from spss"
        send_result('Can not open File %s' % DBname,Start,Finish)
        spss_Output(DBname)

def init_Vars(FilePath):
    FilePath=FilePath.encode('string-escape')
    #FilePath= map(os.path.normpath, FilePath)
    FilePath=FilePath.replace('\\','/')
    FilePath=FilePath.replace('/x07','/a')
    FilePath=FilePath.replace('//','/')
    FilePath=FilePath.replace('/x08','/b')
    FilePath=FilePath.replace('/x0b','/v')
    FilePath=FilePath.replace('/x0c','/v')
    print 'this is the file path..................... '+FilePath
    DBname = os.path.split(os.path.normpath(FilePath))[-1]
    #if '\\' in FilePath:
    #    DBname=FilePath.rpartition('\\')[-1]
    #if '/' in FilePath:
    #    DBname=FilePath.rpartition('/')[-1]
    init_Syntax=FilePath
    OutputClose="output close name=%s." % DBname
    OutputNew="output new name=%s." %  DBname
    spss.Submit(OutputClose)
    spss.Submit(OutputNew)
    return (DBname, init_Syntax)

def init_cmds(init_Syntax):
    with open(init_Syntax,'rb') as f:
        BOM_UTF8 = "\xef\xbb\xbf" 
        code = f.read().lstrip(BOM_UTF8) 
        #r = re.compile('(?<=\.)\s*?^\s*',re.M)
        r = re.compile('(?<=\.)\s*?^\s*|\s*\Z|\A\s*',re.M)
        cmds = r.split(code) 
        #cmds = re.split("(?<=\\.)%s[ \t]*"   %    os.linesep, code, flags=re.M) 
        #cmds = re.split(r'(?<=\.)[ \t]*%s' % os.linesep, code, flags=re.M)
        cmds = [cmdx.lstrip() for cmdx in cmds if not cmdx.startswith("*")] 
        return cmds

def run_cmds(cmd,cmd2,cmd3,cmds):
    for cmd in cmds:
        cmd=cmd.replace('\r\n','\n ')
        cmd=cmd.replace('\t',' ')
        print cmd
        spss.Submit(cmd)  
        cmd3=cmd2
        cmd2=cmd       
    return (cmd, cmd2, cmd3)

def send_result(DBname,result,Start,Finish,status,AlertDays,cmd='',cmd2='',cmd3='',errorLevel='', errorMsg=''):
    """ """
    print result + ' was sent for '+DBname
    FinishText = Finish.strftime("%m-%d-%y %H:%M")
    StartText = Start.strftime("%m-%d-%y %H:%M")
    Runtimex = str(Finish-Start)[0:7]
    error_result="""%s %s
    Start             Finish           Runtime Hrs:Min:Sec
    %s    %s   %s """ % (DBname,result,StartText,FinishText,Runtimex)

    error_result_email="""%s <br>
  %s <br> Runtime %s <br>\n""" % (result,DBname,Runtimex)

    with open("k:/meinzer/production/output/Error Log.txt", "r+") as myfile:
        old=myfile.read()
        myfile.seek(0)
        if status==1:
           myfile.write(error_result+"\n\n"+ old)
        if status==0:
           myfile.write(error_result+'\n'+'This was the problem\n'+errorLevel+" "+ errorMsg+'\n'+cmd3+'\n'+cmd2+'\n'+cmd+"\n\n"+ old)
#    with open("k:/meinzer/production/output/email Log.txt", "r+") as emailtext:
#                 olde=emailtext.read()
#                 emailtext.seek(0)
#                 emailtext.write(error_result_email+ olde)
    with open("k:/meinzer/production/output/ErrorCSV.txt", "r+") as ErrorCSV:
                      oldcsv=ErrorCSV.read()
                      ErrorCSV.seek(0)
                      ErrorCSV.write(DBname+','+str(status)+','+FinishText+",0"+','+str(AlertDays)+"\n"+ oldcsv)

def check_saved_new_name(DBname):
    """ check saved new name"""
    with open("k:/meinzer/production/output/text/"+DBname+".txt", "r") as searchfile:
        if 'Warning # 5334' in open("k:/meinzer/production/output/text/"+DBname+".txt", "r").read():
           SavedNewname=True
        else:
           SavedNewname=False   
    return SavedNewname

def get_spss_error(e):
    print 'Error', e
    errorLevel=str(spss.GetLastErrorLevel())
    errorMsg=spss.GetLastErrorMessage()
    return (errorLevel, errorMsg)

def spss_Output(DBname):
    """ """
    outputtext="output export /text documentfile='k:/meinzer/production/output/text/%s.txt'." %  DBname
    outputspv="output save outfile='k:/meinzer/production/output/%s.spv'." % DBname
    spss.Submit(outputspv)  
    spss.Submit(outputtext)

main(Files)

end program.
```